# Spring-Integration-Transformer

Tags: spring-integration, transformer-model

I am publishing a MapMessage on IBM MQ and using SI i am receiving that message (using jms:inbound-gateway). I want to transform this Map into an object so i am using map-to-object-transformer. When i receive a message and transformer tries to transform this map into an object i am getting ClassCastException.

### MapMessage Publisher

```
public void sendMapMessage(){
        jmsTemplate102.send(sendQueue,
            new MessageCreator() {
                public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {

                    return getEventMap(session);
                }

                public Message getEventMap(Session session){
                    MapMessage mapMsg = null;
                    try {
                        mapMsg = session.createMapMessage();    
                        mapMsg.setStringProperty("batchId", "123987");
                        mapMsg.setStringProperty("eventType", "ABCD");
                        mapMsg.setStringProperty("client", "CORP");

                    } catch (JMSException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return mapMsg;
                }
            });
    }
```

---

### JMS Inbound Gateway

```
<int-jms:inbound-gateway id="jmsInGateway" request-destination="receiverQueue" 
                                           request-channel="events"
                                           concurrent-consumers="1"
                                           max-concurrent-consumers="4"
                                           acknowledge="auto"
                                           />

<int:channel id="etlEvents"/>

<int:map-to-object-transformer input-channel="etlEvents" output-channel="etlEvents" ref="etlEvent"/>
```

---

Exception

```
JMS Message class: jms_text
  JMSType:         null
  JMSDeliveryMode: 2
  JMSExpiration:   0
  JMSPriority:     4
  JMSMessageID:    ID:414d5120414344534430513720202020537502dd20130f02
  JMSTimestamp:    1404142195240
  JMSCorrelationID:null
  JMSDestination:  null
  JMSReplyTo:      null
  JMSRedelivered:  false
  JMS_IBM_PutDate:20140630
  JMSXAppID:Websphere MQ Client for Java
  JMS_IBM_Format:MQSTR   
  JMS_IBM_PutApplType:28
  JMS_IBM_MsgType:8
  JMSXUserID:mqcls1      
  JMS_IBM_PutTime:15295524
  JMSXDeliveryCount:1
<map></map>] to integration Message payload [<map></map>]
2014-06-30 10:48:13,356 DEBUG [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-1] channel.DirectChannel - preSend on channel 'etlEvents', message: [Payload String content=<map></map>][Headers={JMS_IBM_Format=MQSTR   , errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@581bce9a, jms_timestamp=1404142195240, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@581bce9a, JMSXUserID=mqcls1      , JMS_IBM_PutApplType=28, JMS_IBM_MsgType=8, JMS_IBM_PutDate=20140630, jms_messageId=ID:414d5120414344534430513720202020537502dd20130f02, JMS_IBM_PutTime=15295524, JMSXDeliveryCount=1, jms_redelivered=false, priority=4, JMSXAppID=Websphere MQ Client for Java, id=f8aacfea-e655-e19d-1b7f-fd99389bf095, timestamp=1404139693356}]
2014-06-30 10:48:13,356 DEBUG [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-1] transformer.MessageTransformingHandler - org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler#0 received message: [Payload String content=<map></map>][Headers={JMS_IBM_Format=MQSTR   , errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@581bce9a, jms_timestamp=1404142195240, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@581bce9a, JMSXUserID=mqcls1      , JMS_IBM_PutApplType=28, JMS_IBM_MsgType=8, JMS_IBM_PutDate=20140630, jms_messageId=ID:414d5120414344534430513720202020537502dd20130f02, JMS_IBM_PutTime=15295524, JMSXDeliveryCount=1, jms_redelivered=false, priority=4, JMSXAppID=Websphere MQ Client for Java, id=f8aacfea-e655-e19d-1b7f-fd99389bf095, timestamp=1404139693356}]
2014-06-30 10:48:13,356 WARN  [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-1] jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener$GatewayDelegate - failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive
org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: failed to transform message
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:44)
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:68)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:170)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:255)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:114)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:154)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:44)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:75)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:250)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:224)
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener$GatewayDelegate.sendAndReceiveMessage(ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.java:485)
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.onMessage(ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.java:330)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:537)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:497)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:468)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1102)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:991)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MapToObjectTransformer.transformPayload(MapToObjectTransformer.java:41)
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.AbstractPayloadTransformer.doTransform(AbstractPayloadTransformer.java:33)
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:33)
    ... 25 more
2014-06-30 10:48:13,387 WARN  [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-1] listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: failed to transform message
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:44)
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:68)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:170)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:255)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:114)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:154)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:44)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:75)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:250)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:224)
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener$GatewayDelegate.sendAndReceiveMessage(ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.java:485)
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.onMessage(ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.java:330)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:537)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:497)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:468)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1102)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:991)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MapToObjectTransformer.transformPayload(MapToObjectTransformer.java:41)
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.AbstractPayloadTransformer.doTransform(AbstractPayloadTransformer.java:33)
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:33)
    ... 25 more
```

---

Sorry for the bad formatting.

Can anyone please tell me what wrong i am doing here ?

Comment: forgot to add the transformer <int:channel id="etlEvents"/>   <int:map-to-object-transformer input-channel="etlEvents" output-channel="etlEvents" ref="etlEvent"/>

Comment: Added to the answer a trick to check the `JmsMessage` type and see which `payload` is populated from that message.

Comment: Can't it a `wrong` message in the queue? However about to clean the MQ queue and try one more time?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `IBM MQ` doesn't support `MapMessage`. The exaption said that you receive:

> JMS Message class: jms_text

And you get just a `TextMessage` with xml `<map></map>`:

> `[Payload String content=<map></map>]`

**UPDATE**

OK: let IBM MQ supports the `MapMessage`. So, would be great, if you check it in the DEBUG for the `ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener`. Or at least switch on the DEBUG logging level for that class and show here the result of its expression:

```
logger.debug("converted JMS Message [" + jmsMessage + "] to integration Message payload [" + result + "]");
```

**UPDATE 2**

I see, sorry. Can't it a wrong message in the queue? However about to clean the MQ queue and try one more time? Because now it is `String` and it is just `<map></map>`. As you see there is no your sent content. Actually the framework works well with this issue and can't complain, because your message is wrong.

Comment: Its already enabled and result of that expression is printed already in original post. JMS Message class: jms_text JMSType: null JMSDeliveryMode: 2 JMSExpiration: 0 JMSPriority: 4 JMSMessageID: ID:414d5120414344534430513720202020537502dd20130f02 JMSTimestamp: 1404142195240 JMSCorrelationID:null JMSDestination: null JMSReplyTo: null JMSRedelivered: false JMS_IBM_PutDate:20140630 JMSXAppID:Websphere MQ Client for Java JMS_IBM_Format:MQSTR JMS_IBM_PutApplType:28 JMS_IBM_MsgType:8 JMSXUserID:mqcls1 JMS_IBM_PutTime:15295524 JMSXDeliveryCount:1
<map></map>] to integration Message payload [<map></map